# Can you set up a wordpress (multi-site) network to work across multiple hosting accounts?

Tags: wordpress

I would like to manage multiple sites running as part of a single wordpress network, but I don't want to personally host each of the individual sites. I don't mind if my database holds all the tables for each site, but I don't want to be the sole host for all the files, etc for each site. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly when you say "manage multiple sites" & "work across multiple hosting accounts", I believe you can do this easily.

There is a great tool for remotely manging multiple wp sites ... the sites don't even have to be all your own sites. They can be clients sites or a mix of your own and client sites.

They can be on multiple servers and multiple hosting accounts.

You simply add a plugin to each wp site you want to manage remotely. When you login to your account, you have access to all the admins of all the sites without further logins. You can install plugins en-mass or update them en-mass or individually or in groups (that you may have setup previously).

Check out: [http://managewp.com](http://managewp.com/)

Have fun
J

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no, you can't do this. But [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48232/can-you-set-up-a-wordpress-multi-site-network-to-work-across-multiple-hosting)'s some helpful elaboration from wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

If "manage multiple sites across servers/Domains" includes facilitating marketing and SEO related activities, then you can also load a free marketing plugin from https://wordpress.org/plugins/seosamba-webmasters/ that will let you connect all sites with Google Webmasters, track search rankings, deploy web analytics, and also do social marketing, all from a single cloud dashboard,

it completes nicely what Jackson has recommended.

There's also a premium version that let you SEO all your sites from a single rule engine at https://www.seosamba.com 
And it does work also for your own sites or your client sites as you can private-label it.

Cheers